# Loop on a array, but string is not displayed

Tags: handlebars.js

I have an object who have this structure

```
objects: Object
  hasParams: true
  listParamNames: Array[2]
0: "dateFrom"
1: "dateTo"
```

i tried to display listParamNames value with

```
{{#each objects.listParamNames}}
<input type="text" id="listParamNames{{@index}}" name="listParamNames[{{@index}}]" value="{{@index}}" >
{{/each}}
```

but that display only 0, 1...